# How to create a My Territory Accounts List View that uses Enterprise Territory Management

Tags: lightning, reporting, list-view, territory-management

The "My territories" list view is returning 0 records. I have recently enabled Enterprise Territory Management and created a Model that is in status "Planning".

[image]

I have assigned Accounts and Users to territories. So I would expect to see records within the List View in the image above.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "My territories' accounts" and "My territory team's accounts" filters for the Account List views only display records if the model is in "Active" status.

Note: Even if you preview the model and see that the "Assigned territories" and "Users in Assigned territories" related lists are populated it will not populate the list views.